# Массив бинов в Spring

Tags: spring, java

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как реализовать такой функционал: для бина есть 2 класса реализации: класс1, класс2, в конфиге выбирается один из этих классов, и на выходе я хочу получить массив этих бинов. То есть, грубо говоря, определение в конфиге для одного бина, а в рантайме в программе я хочу, чтоб таких бинов был массив. Такое можно сделать средствами Spring? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда - то заканчивал тренинг . Можно было выбирать как вытаскивать данные из БД . Используя чисто JDBC или Hibernate . Писал класс который конфигится в xml и потом  рантайме с его помощью создавал нужный класс . Приблизительный код класса :

```
public class CarDaoFactory {
    private CarDao dao;
    private PersistanceType persistanceType;

    public PersistanceType getPersistanceType() {
        return persistanceType;
    }

    public void setPersistanceType(PersistanceType persistanceType) {
        this.persistanceType = persistanceType;
    }

    public CarDao getCarDao() throws DataLayerException {

    switch (persistanceType) {

        case JDBC : dao = JDBCCarDao.getInstance();  break;
        case Hibernate : dao = HibernateCarDao.getInstance(); break;
    }

    return dao;
    }
}

public enum PersistanceType {
    JDBC,Hibernate
}
```

-

```
<bean id="carDaoFactory" class="com.epam.dao.factory.CarDaoFactory"
        scope="singleton">
    <property name="persistanceType">
        <value>JDBC</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Спасибо,  так и сделал